# Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I noticed that there was a [terminator3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator3) tage and a [rise-of-the-machines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rise-of-the-machines). As they are the same film I tried to suggest rise-of-the-machines as a synonym of the terminator3 tag. However I received the following error:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

I have no idea what that means, but it seems strange that I can't suggest a synonym, when it is clearly the same film.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a carry-over from Stack Overflow, where numbers are used to differentiate between different versions of software (e.g. **foo**, **foo2** and **foo42**). Here are a few Meta.se posts describing a similar problem:

- [Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157869)
- [Version Specific Tag Validation on Tag Synonym Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121457)

Since we also have a **terminator** tag, it thinks you’re talking about v3 of the Terminator software. (I’ve also seen reports that it treats any tag that begins or ends with a digit as version-specific, but I can’t confirm that.)

I’ve also never seen a Meta post that properly explains or justifies this feature; that’s just how SO, and hence SE, treats version-specific synonyms.

---

As a side note, do we want to make a Terminator 3 tag that incorporates both the number and the name? The Terminator 2 tag is [terminator2-judgement-day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator2-judgement-day), so perhaps [terminator3-rise-of-the-machines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator3-rise-of-the-machines)?

Just a thought.

Comment: I would back that new tag idea

Comment: V3 of terminator software: finally out of Beta

Comment: @Moogle Synonym proposed: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4931/3567

Answer (score 3):

There's now a [rise-of-the-machines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rise-of-the-machines) -> [terminator3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator3) synonym.