# Tag synonym: “terminator3-rise-of-the-machines”

Tags: support, tags

We currently have two tags to refer to the third Terminator film:

- [terminator3](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator3) (2 questions)
- [rise-of-the-machines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rise-of-the-machines) (1 question)

The tag for the second Terminator film unifies both the number and the title:

- [terminator2-judgement-day](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator2-judgement-day) (13 questions)

I propose unifying the two tags above into a single tag:

- [terminator3-rise-of-the-machines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator3-rise-of-the-machines)

Originally suggested in my answer to [Failed to propose synonym: Version specific synonym?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/3567)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

[image: Error message when trying to create a tag that long.]

Comment: You spoilsport.